# Qgis2Web project improvments basemaps

Tags: basemap, qgis2web

[image]I am using Qgis2Web to create a webmap application. I have choose a basemap but it dosen't appears in the layerlist(collapsed layerlist).How could I edit the exported code (probably the qgis2web.js file ) in order to do this.

What i actually want to do is to add 2 or more basemaps in the final project and let the user choose from the layerlist.

Comment: Are you exporting your webmap in Leaflet format or OpenLayers? What you describe should work, so we need to find out where the problem lies.

Comment: I use OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select multiple basemaps in the qgis2web interface. Click the first, then CTRL-click (PC)/command-click (Mac) the additional ones you need. That then puts all the basemaps into the layers list, allowing them to choose which to display.